# MySQL display multiple data for each user

Tags: mysql

I have table:

t_patients (id is auto_increment)

| id | patient_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2023-01-10 |
| 2 | 200 | 2023-01-11 |
| 3 | 100 | 2023-01-15 |

the result need like this:

| patient_id | 1st come | 2nd come | 3rd come |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2023-01-10 | 2023-01-15 | x |
| 200 | 2023-01-11 | x | x |

I have googling for this but still didn't find the exact output as needed. What query the SQL should be?

Comment: What are your tries? Did you try googling "pivot a table" ?

Comment: How much maximal **come** of each patient?

Comment: @LeandroBardelli I just tried INNER JOIN, I only know it

Comment: @Jordy it is 4 maximum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using [COALESCE function in mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) and conditional aggregation.

> The MySQL COALESCE() function is used for returning the first non-null
> value in a list of expressions. If all the values in the list evaluate
> to NULL, then the COALESCE() function returns NULL.

Here is [a demo using DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/NiPtR3LH).

The following query shall give you the expected output :

```
SELECT 
  patient_id,
  COALESCE(MAX(IF(rn = 1, created_at, NULL)), 'x') AS `1st come`,
  COALESCE(MAX(IF(rn = 2, created_at, NULL)), 'x') AS `2nd come`,
  COALESCE(MAX(IF(rn = 3, created_at, NULL)), 'x') AS `3rd come`
FROM (
  SELECT 
    id,
    patient_id,
    created_at,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY patient_id ORDER BY created_at) AS rn
  FROM t_patients
) AS t
GROUP BY patient_id;
```

Output :

| patient_id | 1st come | 2nd come | 3rd come |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2023-01-10 | 2023-01-15 | x |
| 200 | 2023-01-11 | x | x |

Comment: Ahh now I learn new function: COALESCE. Your query is 100% exactly correct! Thank you so much @Tushar, GBU

Comment: Thank you both for giving me food for thought. That's a classic question of table pivoting from Rian and a good show of window function from Tushar. Being stuck to version 5.7, I wrote a query without using it . Also, I find it's possible to use an aggregation function without  COALESCE. Please check it out if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a query without using window function (as MySQL 5.7 and below do not support it). To make things more exciting, let's add a few rows:

```
create table t_patients (id int primary key auto_increment,patient_id int,create_at date);
insert t_patients values(default,100,'2023-01-10'),
(default,200,'2023-01-11'),
(default,100,'2023-01-15'),
(default,300,'2023-01-15'),
(default,200,'2023-01-16'),
(default,100,'2023-01-16'),
(default,300,'2023-01-17'),
(default,300,'2023-01-18');

select * from t_patients;
+----+------------+------------+
| id | patient_id | create_at  |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 |        100 | 2023-01-10 |
|  2 |        200 | 2023-01-11 |
|  3 |        100 | 2023-01-15 |
|  4 |        300 | 2023-01-15 |
|  5 |        200 | 2023-01-16 |
|  6 |        100 | 2023-01-16 |
|  7 |        300 | 2023-01-17 |
|  8 |        300 | 2023-01-18 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

After that, let's write the query which lines up each patient_id based on each patient's create_at value. A row_id is given for each of a patient's create_at value , which starts from 1. Note, the row_id value shall be reset to 1 whenever patient_id changes, so every patient_id can have its row_id start from 1.

```
select patient_id,create_at , 
case @pid when patient_id then  @row_id:=@row_id+1 else  @row_id:=1 end as row_id ,
case when @pid!=patient_id then @pid:=patient_id else @pid end as track_pid -- the track_pid serves to keep the @pid value up to date 
from
t_patients,
(select @row_id:=0,@pid:=(select max(patient_id) from t_patients) ) t
order by patient_id , create_at
;
+------------+------------+--------+-----------+
| patient_id | create_at  | row_id | track_pid |
+------------+------------+--------+-----------+
|        100 | 2023-01-10 |      1 |       100 |
|        100 | 2023-01-15 |      2 |       100 |
|        100 | 2023-01-16 |      3 |       100 |
|        200 | 2023-01-11 |      1 |       200 |
|        200 | 2023-01-16 |      2 |       200 |
|        300 | 2023-01-15 |      1 |       300 |
|        300 | 2023-01-17 |      2 |       300 |
|        300 | 2023-01-18 |      3 |       300 |
+------------+------------+--------+-----------+
```

The above query is then used as a derived table (aliased as `tb` ) for our main query, which does the table pivoting job. Note: Instead of using the `coalesce` function, here I decided to use `min()` function . As numbers serving as strings come before letters in ascii, so `min()` will pick up the create_at over letter `x` when a create_at value exists .

```
select patient_id,
min(case when row_id=1 then create_at else 'x' end) 1st,
min(case when row_id=2 then create_at else 'x' end) 2nd,
min(case when row_id=3 then create_at else 'x' end) 3rd,
min(case when row_id=4 then create_at else 'x' end) 4th
from
    (select patient_id,create_at , 
    case @pid when patient_id then  @row_id:=@row_id+1 else  @row_id:=1 end as row_id ,
    case when @pid!=patient_id then @pid:=patient_id else @pid end as track_pid
    from
    t_patients,(select @row_id:=0,@pid:=(select max(patient_id) from t_patients) ) t
    order by patient_id , create_at) tb
group by patient_id
order by patient_id
;

+------------+------------+------------+------------+------+
| patient_id | 1st        | 2nd        | 3rd        | 4th  |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------+
|        100 | 2023-01-10 | 2023-01-15 | 2023-01-16 | x    |
|        200 | 2023-01-11 | 2023-01-16 | x          | x    |
|        300 | 2023-01-15 | 2023-01-17 | 2023-01-18 | x    |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------+
```